# OpenGL - Texture coordinates on quad

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I have no idea what's wrong. Everything seems to be fine. Here's code (texture is loaded, just drawing) :

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    float TX1,TX2,TY1,TY2;

    TX1=some_numbers_check_below_code;
    TX2=some_numbers_check_below_code;
    TY1=some_numbers_check_below_code;
    TY2=some_numbers_check_below_code;

    glTexCoord2f(TX1,TY2);
    glVertex3f( float(RectOutput.x), float(RectOutput.y), 0.0f );

    glTexCoord2f(TX2,TY2);
    glVertex3f( float(RectOutput.x+InputWidth), float(RectOutput.y), 0.0f );

    glTexCoord2i(TX2,TY1);
    glVertex3f( float(RectOutput.x+InputWidth), float(RectOutput.y+InputHeight), 0.0f );(InputY)/float(Input.H)) );

    glTexCoord2f(TX1,TY1);
    glVertex3f( float(RectOutput.x), float(RectOutput.y+InputHeight), 0.0f );

glEnd();
```

It's okay with :

```
TX1=0.0;
TX2=1.0;
TY1=1.0;
TY2=0.0;
```

(Good : https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bj8i.png)

But gets broken with (eg.) :

```
TX1=0.0;
TX2=0.5;
TY1=1.0;
TY2=0.5;
```

(Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xem99.png)

Really, it annoys me. Probably problem isn't in this code. Everything should be fine ... but it's not.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about you're doing and I'm not an expert on opengl, but it seems that you miss somehow send the texture coordinates to one of the triangles of the plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I have no idea what's wrong. Everything seems to be fine". Great then, no need to answer!

You should first explain what do you expect to get in second case. I am not an OpenGL expert, but your second set of coordinates seem broken.

The first one: `0,0 -> 1,0 -> 1,1 -> 0,1`:

```
  0     1
0 x---->x
  |     |
  |     |
  |     v
1 x<----x
```

The second one: `0,.5 -> .5,.5 -> .5,1 -> 0,1`:

```
  0     1
0 +-----+
  |     |
  x->x  |
  |  v  |
1 +--x->x
```

If you want to scale the texture (but I don't know as you haven't written what is supposed to be the result) then this is obviously wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answer but I fixed it myself. It was just stupid mistake glTexCoord2i insted of glTexCoord2f ;)

Answer (score 2):

Oh ... I feel stupid. Sorry for taking time. Here's error :

glTexCoord2i(TX2,TY1);

I should use glTexCoord2 **f** not **i** ... Just forgot to change it ...